# Javascript click handlers

Tags: css, html, web, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

The task is :

[image]

I have done the form and the design bit for the web page but never came across this push: function() in javascript

I am confused on how to approach or do this task any help will be appreciated! Thank you :)

```js
 var _itq = {
   push: function() {
     console.log.apply(console, arguments);
   }
 };

 _itq.push("_itq", "initialised", "ok");
```

```html
<form id="commentForm" method="get" action="">

  <div class="form-group">

    <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">

    <div>

      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" Enter Your Name" pattern=".{2,}" required title="2 characters minimum">


    </div>

    <div>

      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Password" pattern=".{5,10}" required title="5 to 10 characters">


    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-info">Sign Up</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Not clear what the problem is. Grab email and just push it into this array.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this

Your HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-info" onclick="fillarr()">Sign Up</button>
```

JS:

```
function fillarr(){
_itq.push(document.getElementById("emailId").value, document.getElementById("nameId").value);
}
```

You still need to add an ID for your Email and Name field though

Answer (score 0):

Here is the second question, this should set you on the right path for question 1.

```
document.getElementById('commentForm').onsubmit = function() { // attach to form submit
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;          // get the email value (add id="email" to the email input in the html)
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;            // get the name (add id="name" to the name input in the html)
  var initials = name.split(' ').map(function(v, i) {          // get the initials by splitting
    return v[0]                                                // on space and taking the 1st char
  }).join('');
  _itq.push(email, initials); // pass into your push
  return false;               // return false to stop the submit (optional depending on requirements)
};
```

working snippet below

```js
var _itq = {
  push: function() {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
  }
};

_itq.push("_itq", "initialised", "ok");

document.getElementById('commentForm').onsubmit = function() {
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var initials = name.split(' ').map(function(v, i) {
    return v[0]
  }).join('');
  _itq.push(email, initials);
  return false;
};
```

```html
<form id="commentForm" method="get" action="">

  <div class="form-group">

    <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">

    <div>

      <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" Enter Your Name" pattern=".{2,}" required title="2 characters minimum">


    </div>

    <div>

      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Password" pattern=".{5,10}" required title="5 to 10 characters">


    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-info">Sign Up</button>
  </div>

</form>
```